# Playing VOD Stream using Kaltura Android Client

Tags: android, kaltura

I have a Kaltura CE 10.0.0 Single Server Setup.

I am trying to play a a video stored on a Kaltura using Kaltura Demo Android Client.
But I get Error as `Invalid Data format. Select Another!`.

After debugging I found that, there is call to service function listAllFlavorsFromContext as below:

```
FlavorAsset.listAllFlavorsFromContext(TAG, entryId,"widevine_mbr,widevine,iphonenew");
```

Which returns 0 sized list as server fails to return flour of the video which is in

```
widevine_mbr,widevine,iphonenew
```

So for testing I tried different flavors as `mobile,iphone,web,iphonenew`, using these flavors I got the list, but player tires to play it using HLS, using m3u8 file.
But it also Fail as sub m3u8 files listed in master m3u8 are missing.

I checked for flavors of this entry ID, and there are warnings displayed under Description for these flavors, but when i play the flavor file from the PC browser then it plays properly:

```
video warnings: 2107,288,2500#The target flavor bitrate (288) does not
comply with the requested bitrate (2500).; 2106,#Redundant bitrate.
audio warnings: 2106,#Redundant bitrate.

video warnings: 2112,ffmpeg-aux#The transcoder (ffmpeg-aux) can not handle this content.
audio warnings: 2106,#Redundant bitrate.
```

Are these just warnings or this flavor of the entry is not available because of these warnings? I see status of the flavor as Ready in KMC.

Can someone please help me on this, as I am stuck on this for so long.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem was my kaltura setup was not streaming HLS streams which Android client was trying to play, so i modified the client code and hard coded to receive progressive download stream then it got working. Also one more change in `listAllFlavorsFromContext` passed tab of the video as mobile which returned me all the video list which i was getting as 0.

Comment: @A_user i know it's late to comment on this thread. i have just started using kaltura sdk and it just bewilders me .It provides kaltura configurations and Kalturaclient class wh9ic uses asynctask  evry now and then.. i mean multithreading is kept on countryside while making library.. i want to know how to use kaltura using retrofit and other libraries.Please share your valuable experience whith kaltura develpoment